# Translating "peripheral" (computer device)

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

In English, "[peripheral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral)" or "peripheral device" refers to most devices that can be connected to a computer: keyboards, mice, digital cameras, external hard drives, webcams, etc.

Is there an equivalent word in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "periférico". It can be used both as a noun ("Un teclado es un periférico") and as an adjective ("Un teclado es un dispositivo periférico").

More information in [wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=peripheral).

Answer (score 5):

I think two good alternatives are `periférico` used in Spain and `dispositivo` used in Latin America.

Comment: *Periférico* is also used in Latin America.

Comment: Mexican here, negativo en dispositivo; Les llamamos periféricos.